# Use custom namespace in Xaml parsed code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I created a custom control and I'm trying to use this control by using the Xaml Parser in C#, but it seems that the parser doesn't recognize the namespace of the control.

```
var xaml = @"
<Paragraph
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
    xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008""
    xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006""
    xmlns:custom=""using:Sandbox.Custom_Controls""
    mc:Ignorable=""d"">
    <custom:Strike Text=""Lorem ipsum""/>
</Paragraph>";

Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

The XamlReader throws the following exception: "The type 'Strike' was not found. [Line: 1 Position: 345]".

I tested my control in a normal Xaml file and it works, so it must have something to do width the Xaml Reader.

Comment: Why don't you add your `custom` namespace to page where your `RichTextBlock` Resides and then decrease the complexity?

Comment: Because its the parser that fails, and the parser has nothing to do with the page I want to put the control into.

Comment: did you find a solution for it? I have a similar issue

Comment: No sorry, I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change this

```
"xmlns:custom=\"using:Sandbox.Custom_Controls\" "
```

to this:

```
"xmlns:custom=\"clr-namespace:Sandbox.Custom_Controls\" "
```

?

Comment: "The type 'Strike' was not found because 'clr-namespace:Sandbox.Custom_Controls' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 1 Position: 353]"

Comment: @mjw: Sorry I was in the wrong kind of xaml (wpf desktop).

Comment: I just added a UWP tag, sorry